# How can make a line graph out of a dataframe but make the line that corresponds to the last n amount of rows be differently colored or styled?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, graph

I have a dataframe that contains a column of numerical values.

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk2n4.png)

I want to create a line plot for the column and graph it in a way that the line that corresponds to the last 6 rows of the dataframe are different (maybe a different color or have it as broken lines). The picture below shows a line graph with a single-colored line.

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVdeh.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. Take a minute to read -> [How to create minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks

Comment: Just make 2 plots in one figure, where you first plot `df.iloc[:-6]` and then plot `df.tail(6)`. Easier to do by plotting with matplotlib directly, instead of the `df.plot()` function from pandas.

Comment: @NielsHenkens Managed to do it with the help of your comment, thanks!

Comment: @MarcNicholas: Great!